# Exception when running windows 10 in qemu

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, raspberry-pi, qemu

So I've downloaded the windows 10 iso file on raspbian, and I've tried running it on qemu, but it gives the following error:
[image: exception]

how do I fix this?

Comment: You cannot run Windows 10 x86 on a ARM processor even within a VM

Comment: @Ramhound could you list some os's I could run on ARM?

Comment: Windows 10 on ARM there is even a GitHub project that documents the process (license is entirely up to you)

Comment: @Ramhound But where do I find this "Windows 10 on ARM"?

Comment: GIYF - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/

Comment: I actually think you can run cross arch on qemu in theory. Not sure how windows 10 support would be tho

Comment: @SaishShankar - What does your research indicate? [Here is a deployment script for compatible RPI devices](https://github.com/WOA-Project/WOA-Deployer-Rpi).  Licensing is a real problem since you cannot purchase one

Comment: @Ramhound I saw the WOA deployer, but I'm using a raspberry pi 4, not a raspberry pi 3.